# How do I write a query that will only return accounts that have a sale date less than today?

Tags: sql, where-clause

On the surface this seems a simple where clause but given the data below I only want my query to return account B's sales transactions, with a condition stating show me only those accounts that don't have any sales date beyond 2015.

```
Acct     Sale Date

A       2030
A       2018
A       2015
B       2015
B       2014
B       2013
C       2020
C       2015
C       2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to only return acct's with last SaleDate <= 2015:

```
select acct
from tablename
group by acct
having max(SaleDate) <= 2015
```

If you want all columns, and all rows, for these accounts:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
join (select acct, max(SaleDate) as maxSaleDate
      from tablename
      group by acct) t2
   on t.acct = t2.acct
where t2.maxSaleDate <= 2015
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine having and where? like: select acct from tablename group by acct having min(saledate) >= 2015 where acct in ('A','B');

Comment: Yes, WHERE can be used to filter away rows before GROUP BY and HAVING are performed. Put WHERE  before GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you need every transaction in your result, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable as T
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
                 WHERE SaleDate >= 2015
                 AND Acct = T.Acct);
```